# Sort in ascending numerical order columns of a lot of files

Tags: unix

I have around 1600 files in a folder (with different file names but in the file name it occurs always the word "sample") that look like this:

File1: #_sample.txt

```
    Name   Freq.MB.0002    Freq.MB.0146    Freq.MB.0106    Freq.MB.0136     .......
      A         -2              -12             -34             123
```

File2: #_sample.txt

```
    Name    Freq.MB.0106    Freq.MB.0002    Freq.MB.0136    Freq.MB.0146     .......
      C         -12              1            1000             -126
```

up to around 1600 files.

I would like to sort each file and specifically each column name in each file in ascending numerical order, so that for file1 the output will be:

File1: #_sample.txt

```
    Name   Freq.MB.0002    Freq.MB.0106     Freq.MB.0136       Freq.MB.0146     .......
      A         -2            -34                123              -12
```

I tried to run an R based script but it does not work because of the high number of files.

Comment: Do you have an R based script that can work on a single file at a time?

Comment: Right, Nathan, because with this you could just do `for sample in dir/*sample*.txt; do ./script.r "$sample" > "$sample.sorted"; done`

Comment: Yes, I have, but it seems not to work..no Error, no Warnings but also no output..

Comment: In that case, can you post your R code so we can help you debug it?  You should then add the R tag to yhe question.

Comment: Ok, no problem, but I'm still working on trying to solve the problem. Still some attempt.